# css background colour formatting issue

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with the white background on my mainbody div. I have had to specify a fixed px and this is 750px. I dont want to have to do this I want to just be able to use auto. This is because I need to use the same CSS file for other pages and they will be different heights. Also when using the value of height: auto on the manibody div it dosent cover all the content in that div.

Here is a link to see what its like http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=KksjUfFlxS

Please can you help me to be able to fix this.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Home || Web Design Coursework</title>

<meta name="description" content="">

<meta name="author" content="Elliott Davidson">

<meta name="language" content="english">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <!-- start of header -->

    <div id="header">

        <img src="images/header-image.png" width="980" height="170" alt="kayaking header logo" /> </div>

    </div><!-- end of header -->

    <!-- start of navigation bar -->

    <div id="navmenu">

        <ul id="list-nav">

            <li id="topnavleft"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

            <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>

            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

            <li><a href="kayaking-di">Kayaking Disciplines</a></li>

            <li id="topnavright"><a href="links.html">Useful links</a></li>

        </ul><!-- ul end list-nav -->

    </div><!-- div end navmenu -->

    <div id="mainbody">

        <div id="homepagevideo">

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3WabVsBugGQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div><!-- end div homepagevideo -->

        <div id="homepagekayakingdisciplines">

            <h1 id="homepageh1kayakingdiscipline">Kayaking Disciplines</h1>

            <p>Aliquid delicatissimi et vix. Ut cum tation ridens. Mea ei impetus gubergren, sit natum doming quodsi et. Usu cu sonet debitis. Mea nullam tamquam ea. Ex vis vocibus splendide, ut eum ullum assum impedit.</p>

            <p>Decore facete mei ei. Eam ea maluisset dissentias, graece labore ocurreret has eu. Cu usu quem officiis maiestatis, cu quis assueverit mea. Primis deserunt consectetuer quo et, vim numquam aliquam eruditi ut.</p>

            <p>Sint erroribus imperdiet ex quo, et sit habeo dolorum molestiae, commodo dissentiet no duo. Mucius essent repudiare te pri, te tale accumsan reprimique pro. Mel cu ignota argumentum. Vis dolor efficiantur ex, ei mei reque oporteat percipitur. Sea corrumpit voluptaria referrentur ea, ei sensibus definitionem vel. No verterem elaboraret sit, velit apeirian vim ea.</p>

        </div><!-- end div homepagekayakingdisciplines -->

        <div id="homepagedesign">

            <h2>Design</h2>

            <p>Dicat adversarium nam at, ei saepe dictas pri. Ad aliquid meliore fastidii pro, duo appareat apeirian ea, vix ei maiorum luptatum quaerendum. Est ut vivendum oportere efficiendi, vim et brute nusquam, justo accumsan inimicus ex vis. Eum dicant mollis denique cu, an fastidii ocurreret instructior sit. His discere mediocrem no, an sit recteque tincidunt.</p>

<p>Mea ea animal inciderint, cum nulla saepe libris an. Modo meliore argumentum vel ei, mei cu option facilisis. Et enim detraxit vix. In clita mollis feugiat quo. Nobis soluta pri te, cum brute latine cotidieque ei.</p>

        </div><!-- end div homepagedesign -->

        <div id="homepageaboutme">

            <h3>About</h3>

            <p>Dicat adversarium nam at, ei saepe dictas pri. Ad aliquid meliore fastidii pro, duo appareat apeirian ea, vix ei maiorum luptatum quaerendum. Est ut vivendum oportere efficiendi, vim et brute nusquam, justo accumsan inimicus ex vis.</p>

        </div><!-- end div homepageaboutme -->

        <div id="homepagelinks">

            <h3>Links</h3>

            <p>Dicat adversarium nam at, ei saepe dictas pri. Ad aliquid meliore fastidii pro, duo appareat apeirian ea, vix ei maiorum luptatum quaerendum. Est ut vivendum oportere efficiendi, vim et brute nusquam, justo accumsan inimicus ex vis.</p>

        </div><!-- end div homepagelinks -->

    </div><!-- end div mainbody -->

    <div id="footer">

        <div id="footerimage">

            <img src="images/footer-waves.jpg" width="980" height="140" alt="waves" />

            <div id="footertext"> 

                <div id="footernavmenu">

                    <ul id="list-footer-nav">

                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                        <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>

                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

                        <li><a href="kayaking-di">kayaking Disciplines</a></li>

                        <li><a href="links.html">Useful links</a></li>

                    </ul><!-- ul end list-footer-nav -->

                </div><!-- div end footernavmenu -->

                <div id="copyright">

                    <div class="copyrigttext">

                        Copyright © 2013 Elliott Davidson, All Rights Reserved.

                    </div><!-- end div copyrighttext -->

                </div><!-- end div copyright -->

            </div><!-- end div footertext -->          

        </div><!-- footer image --> 

    </div><!-- end of footer -->

</div><!-- end of container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#html, body{
    background-color : #32B7FF;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

#container {
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    width:980px;
    height:auto;
}

/********************************** header **********************************/


/********************************** nav bar **********************************/

#navmenu {
    width : 980px;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    height: 33px;
}

ul#list-nav {
    list-style : none;
    padding : 0;
    background-color : #32B7FF;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul#list-nav li {
    display : inline;
    width : 980px;
    height : 33px;
}

ul#list-nav li a {
    text-decoration : none;
    padding : 8px 0;
    width : 196px;
    background : #1173A8;
    color : #fff;
    float : left;
    text-align : center;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
    background : #4B98C1;
}

ul#list-nav li a:active {
    background : #4B98C1;
}

ul#list-nav li:first-child, ul#list-nav li:last-child {
   border-radius:10px;
}

/********************************** mainbody **********************************/

#mainbody {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:980px;
    height:750px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:-19px;
}

#homepagevideo {
    padding:10px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}

#homepageh1kayakingdiscipline {
    padding-top:5px;
}

#homepagekayakingdisciplines {
    text-align:justify;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#homepagedesign {
    width:470px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;

}

#homepageaboutme {
    width:470px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:right;
    height:auto;

}

#homepagelinks {
    width:470px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:right;
    height:auto;
}

/********************************** footer **********************************/

#footer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:175px;
    width:980;
}

#footertext {
    position:absolute;
    width:980px;
    height:auto;
    bottom: 0
}

#footerimage {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:980px;
    height:140px;
    position: relative;
}

#footernavmenu {
    width : 540px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
}



ul#list-footer-nav li {
    display : inline;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a {
    text-decoration : none;
    width:auto;
    float : left;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:6px;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a:hover {
    color:#4B98C1;
}

ul#list-footer-nav li a:active {
    color:#4B98C1;
}

#copyright {
    width:440px;
    height:auto;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    color:#FFF;
}

.copyrighttext {

}
```

Comment: Do you suppose that we could help you by seeing your full web page code? Ask in summarized way.

Comment: how would I do this is stored locally on my computer?

Comment: you have to know which part is going wrong then only ask.

Comment: I do know and its the background sizing of the mainbody div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an `overflow:auto;` to your `#mainbody`. Thats it.

```
#mainbody {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:980px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:-19px;
    overflow:auto; /* Use THIS one */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bM592/1/)**

Comment: Try `background-size:cover;` and `background-size:contain;` - @user3070541

Comment: Where are you adding them? - @user3070541

Comment: in to the #mainbody div's css

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of the issue and provide a link? - @user3070541

Comment: Edited the same in the main answer. - @user3070541

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by adding a clear like this before closing of `mainbody` div, like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```